# How to detect IE8 compatibility mode

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

How do you detect in JavaScript running in an IE8, whether the browser is using compatibility mode or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's [a good example of how to do it](http://blog.strictly-software.com/2009/03/detecting-ie-8-compatibility-modes-with.html). First Google result for "ie compatibility mode js" BTW.

Comment: Great, don't know how I missed that.